# Shared components between Ionic app and Angular app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to know if there was any documentation or tips on how to style components so they may be used in Angular apps but also in Ionic apps?

Thank you

Comment: can't you style components inside component css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create libraries and then install them. You can either publish the libraries to an npm repository or create a mono repository that hosts the Angular app, the Ionic app and the libraries.

https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/